# Disabling SSL in ElasticSearch and enrolling new nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to start an elasticsearch container with SSL disabled as I want it to be hosted at `http://localhost:9200` (not https). With this I want the ability to enroll new nodes. But as I disable the `http.ssl` (by passing it as environment variable), all the default settings in the elasticsearch.yml also disappear.

I want to keep the other settings including `enrollment.enable` and `transport.ssl` (as they are used for enrolling new nodes) along with creation of certificates (which do not get created if disable the ssl).

So what i did is started the container and disabled http.ssl by myself (with all generated certificates at my disposal), but when i tried to connect other node using the enrollment token it gave me the error that: `security configurations for this node is already configured` and exited. Does anyone if it is possible to do in this way?

Comment: By the way: I'm using the elastic search version 8.8.1.